# How to get back a value based by parameter input using Flask Python API

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I keep recieving the following error when I try to curl this or go to the URL directly i.e. 127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/currentuserid/3/ .. cannot see what is wrong with my code:

**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**

```
@app.route('/api/v1/currentuserid/<userid>/', methods=['GET'])
def api_retrieve_useridd(userid):
    try:
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        _json = request.get_json()
        userid = _json('userid')
        
        if userid and request.method == 'GET':
            sqlQuery = "SELECT username FROM tblUser WHERE user_id=%s"
            bindData = (userid,)
            mycursor.execute(sqlQuery, bindData)
            row_headers=[x[0] for x in mycursor.description] #this will extract row headers
            rv = mycursor.fetchone()
            json_data=[]
            json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,rv)))
            return jsonify(json_data[0])
        else:
            return not_found()
    finally:
        mycursor.close()
```

Comment: I think you should use square brackets to query the value. `userid = _json['userid']` I'm assuming the value is none because you are using a GET instead of a POST request. I do not understand the purpose of the lines. You already get the userid through the rule.

Comment: @Detlef good spot I updated to square brackets but still not luck, when I go to the URL I get the following: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: This is because the value of `_json` is None. Why do you ask for the userid from the json data and do not use the passed parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userid` parameter is already passed to the function via Flask route you defined. So you no need to get the value from `request.get_json()`. You may try below code. By the way, you can enforce the `user_id` type as `int` by doing `<int:userid>` in the route definition.

```
@app.route('/api/v1/currentuserid/<int:userid>/', methods=['GET'])
def api_retrieve_useridd(userid):
    try:
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        
        if userid and request.method == 'GET':
            sqlQuery = "SELECT username FROM tblUser WHERE user_id=%s"
            bindData = (userid,)
            mycursor.execute(sqlQuery, bindData)
            row_headers=[x[0] for x in mycursor.description] #this will extract row headers
            rv = mycursor.fetchone()
            json_data=[]
            json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,rv)))
            return jsonify(json_data[0])
        else:
            return not_found()
    finally:
        mycursor.close()
```